# How to select by non-direct child condition in Xpath?

Tags: xpath

I would like to show an example.

This how the page looks:

```
<a class="aclass">
    <div class="divclass"></div>
    <div id="innerclass">
        <span class="spanclass">Hello</span>
    </div>
</a>

<a class="aclass">
    <div class="divclass"></div>
    <div id="innerclass">
        <span class="spanclass">Pick Delivery Location</span>
    </div>
</a>
```

I want to select anchor tags that have a child (direct or non-direct) span that has the text 'Hello'.

Right now, I do something like this:

```
//a[@class='aclass'][div/span[text() = 'Hello']]
```

I want to be able to select without having to select direct children (div in this case), like this:

```
//a[@class='aclass'][//span[text() = 'Hello']]
```

However, the second one finds all the anchor tags with the class 'aclass' rather than the one with the span with 'Hello' text.

I hope I worded my question clearly. Please feel free to edit if necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your attempt, `//` goes back to the root of the document - effectively you are saying "Give me the `a`s for which there is a `span` *anywhere in the document*", which is why you get them all.

What you need is the **`descendant` axis** :

```
//a[@class='aclass' and descendant::span[text() = 'Hello']]
```

Note I have joined the conditions with `and`, but two separate conditions would also work.